# Unable to locate package USBHID

Tags: debian, package-management, hid

Since this morning my mouse is not working anymore on my Debian 11 google cloud VM, so I restarted the machine but the mouse is still not responding to clicking (my keyboard somehow is).

I checked and it could be a problem with `usbhid`:

```shell
dpkg -l | grep usbhid
```

yields no output meaning somehow it is not installed. But if I try to install it running

```shell
sudo apt install usbhid
```

I get this output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package usbhid
```

I am not sure how to solve this issue, I have been installing a lot of packages lately, perhaps I messed up along the way?

Any help is much appreciatted.

Comment: there is no such package as `usbhid` - what made you think there was? try `lsmod | grep usbhid` - does it show

Comment: usbhid is a driver in the kernel which you can check with a find or locate command. If your kernel has it, and it's loaded, which you check with the lsmod command, then that may not be the issue, rather the "google cloud VM" may come under suspicion.

Comment: when i do `lsmod | grep usbhid` it doesnt show any output

Comment: What happens if you run (as root) `modprobe -v usbhid`? What is the output of `find /lib/modules/$(uname -r) -name 'usbhid*'`?

Comment: The search function at https://packages.debian.org indicates the name of the kernel module's filename is `usbhid.ko` and it's installed under `/lib/modules` in a subdirectory that's named after the version string and architecture suffixes in the `linux-image-VERSION-ARCH` package that installed it.  Perhaps this will help you reconstruct what happened to your driver.

Comment: How are you connected to the cloud VM? A X11-forwarding SSH connection can pass mouse events to remote X11 applications, but a plain SSH or virtual serial console connection will provide mouse functionality only if your terminal emulator can report mouse events over the virtual serial connection. A VNC or RDP session would pass the entire desktop in a single window, and would pass mouse events within that window.

Answer (score 1):

If you have HID devices you should be able to see them in /dev/hid*...
One Debian 12 or Ubuntu 20.04 they look like this...

```
# ls -l /dev/hid*
crw-rw---- 1 root audio 244, 0 Dec 18 15:26 /dev/hidraw0
crw-rw---- 1 root audio 244, 1 Dec 11 08:40 /dev/hidraw1
crw------- 1 root root  244, 2 Dec 11 08:40 /dev/hidraw2
crw------- 1 root root  244, 3 Dec 11 08:40 /dev/hidraw3
crw-rw---- 1 root audio 244, 4 Jan 13 20:16 /dev/hidraw4
crw-rw---- 1 root audio 244, 5 Jan 11 09:56 /dev/hidraw5
crw-rw---- 1 root audio 244, 6 Dec 11 08:40 /dev/hidraw6
crw-rw---- 1 root audio 244, 7 Dec 11 08:40 /dev/hidraw7
```

They always come up on usb audio devices. I don't happen to use any usb mice. As far as I know unless your running some special driver for some special device the drivers are all in the kernel.